# Using multiple left join in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am new to computer field and I am working on SQL. I am using multiple join queries in PostgreSql. I am trying to make inventory management system. I am having 3 tables as follow:

1. inventory_limit_stock: id(int, PK), inventory_id (varchar), product_id(int), min_stock_limit(int)
2. product_inventory: id(int, PK), inventory_id(int), product_id(int), in_stock(int)
3. other_inventory: id(int, PK), product_id, A(int), B(int), C(int)

So I want to show the list of products that are less in stock than minimum limit set in Table 1. `inventory_id` in Table 1 contains value either in number or 'A','B','C'. If it;s number, it refers to Table 2 otherwise refers to Table 1. So for example if `inventory_id` of Table 1 contains value 2, it will check in Table 2 and get the `in_stock` value. While if it contains value 'A' than it refers to Table 3 with column `A` and the value in it will be taken. 
I tried the following query but didn't worked for me.

```
SELECT ils.product_id as limit_prod, ils.inventory_id as limit_inv from inventory_limit_stock ils 
left join product_inventory as pi on pi.product_id = ils.product_id 
left join other_inventory oi on oi.product_id = ils.product_id 
where (COALESCE(ils.min_stock_limit,0) > COALESCE(SUM(pi.in_stock), SUM(oi.limit_inv), 0)) group by ils.product_id, ils.inventory_id
```

I know there are too many mistakes in query, any help would be appreciated. Also sorry for this long elaboration of question, this is my first question here, hope you all understand. Thanks.

**EDIT**

**Table 1 - inventory_limit_stock**

```
id | product_id | inventory_id | min_stock_limit
1  |    121     |      5       |       25
2  |    052     |      B       |       27
3  |    8       |      13      |       11
4  |    121     |      13      |       35
```

**Table 2 - product_inventory**

```
id | product_id | inventory_id | in_stock
1  |    121     |      5       |    42
2  |    742     |      15      |    12
3  |    8       |      13      |    09
4  |    121     |      13      |    25
```

**Table 3 - other_inventory**

```
id | product_id |  A  | B  | C
1  |    121     |  42 | 12 | 11
2  |    052     |  42 | 25 | 25
```

**Result List**
(Should show list with products in_stock quantity < minimum limit)

```
product_id | inventory | minimum_stock_limit | in_stock_available
    8      |     13    |        11           |        9
   121     |     13    |        35           |        25
   052     |     B     |        27           |        25
```

Comment: It would help your question to show some sample data for the 3 tables involved.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added a data to the table for the reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For aggregated  result you should use having and not where

```
SELECT ils.product_id as limit_prod
  , ils.inventory_id as limit_inv 
from inventory_limit_stock ils 
left join product_inventory as pi on pi.product_id = ils.product_id 
left join other_inventory oi on oi.product_id = ils.product_id 
group by ils.product_id, ils.inventory_id
HAVING (COALESCE(ils.min_stock_limit,0) >COALESCE(SUM(pi.quantity), SUM(oi.limit_inv), 0))
```

having clause work on the result of select .. where work on the raw values in table  ..

Comment: In your sample  .. you refer to table1, table2, table3 and in yyour query you use others table  name  . please updated  your question and add  a coherent sample  .. and last  what is the role of table3  is not clear to me

Comment: added the table name. Okay so last table is Other Inventory which consist of columns - id, product_id, A, B, C. This A, B, C columns refers as Inventory that refers to the inventory_id of Table 1. This A, B, C columns contains the value of in_stock products available in this particular inventory. So as stated in my example, in Table 1 I have a product with id '052' with inventory_id 'B', so it will refer to the table 3 with product _id '052' and column 'B'.